# Opening my monitor case?(LG FLATRON W2061TQ)

Tags: display, lg-monitor

I can't figure out how to open up my LG FLATRON computer monitor. I can't find any screw holes or any clips on the outer casing.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?hl=en-GB&v=HoELQMxVePs&gl=SG google turned this up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?hl=en-GB&v=HoELQMxVePs&gl=SG) - which I've linked in the comments, it looks like it snaps together internally - You'd need to get something between the bezel and the other side of the case and pry it apart (which is a pretty typical way in cheaper monitors. You may need to pull the bezel off the monitor as well. I'd recommend investing in a good set of spudgers and guitar picks, and take your time.

Comment: I wonder why that video didn't come up for me. Anyhow thanks for the answer, I had a good set of spudgers but they broke during my last tablet screen repair. So I'm gonna go buy a set and get to work. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I googled for <model> service manual. Couldn't find one but found this.